# Keep fixed table header within mCustomScrollbar

Tags: jquery, html, css

**HTML**

```
 <div class="tableData" id="indexTable">
     <table>
         <thead>
             "..."             
         </thead>
         <tbody>
             "..."             
         </tbody>
     </table>
</div>
```

**CSS (.tableData)**

```
.tableData {
    -webkit-border-radius: 25px;
    -moz-border-radius: 25px;
    border-radius: 25px;

    box-shadow: 10px 10px 5px #000;
    overflow: auto;
    margin: 20px;
    width: 92%;
}
```

**jQuery**

```
var topOffset = parseInt($(".tableData table thead").css('top'));

(function($){
    $(window).load(function(){
        $(".tableData").mCustomScrollbar({
            axis: "yx",
            theme: "dark",
            scrollbarPosition: "outside",
            setHeight: "630",
            setWidth: "1218",
            callbacks: {
                whileScrolling: function() {
                    var contentPos = $(this.mcs.top);
                    $('.tableData thead').css({
                        'top': contentPos + topOffset
                    })
                }
            }
       });
   });
})(jQuery);
```

What I am trying to accomplish is to fix my table headers whilst I am scrolling through the data in the table. I have come across a few methods to try and achieve this:

**1. jQuery.floatThead**

`floatThead` and `mCustomScrollbar` seem to contradict each other in my situation and `floatThead` does not work as expected.

**2. 'position: fixed'**

This seems to be the best solution to what I want. However, if I do this then the `<thead>` goes horizontally off the page as it requires a scroll.

My thinking was that if I could find a way to only fix the Y position of `<thead>` (which is what I tried in the jQuery above) then that would work but not such luck.

Comment: any update on this? With 340+ views, I'm thinking a lot of people want this feature

Comment: I have added an answer. However, it doe snot involve mCustomScrollbar but may be a potential workaround

Answer (score 1):

I ended up moving away from mCustomScrollber in the end as it did not provide enough functionality that I wanted. However, I still wanted to create a fixed header and I found that this piece of code did the trick:

```
function fixHead(table) {
    table.attr("data-item-original-width", table.width());
    table.find('.thead .tr .th').each(function() {
        jQuery(this).attr("data-item-original-width", jQuery(this).width());
    });
    table.find('.tbody .tr:eq(0) .td').each(function() {
        jQuery(this).attr("data-item-original-width", jQuery(this).width());
    });

    var newTable = table.clone();

    table.find('.thead .tr').each(function() {
        jQuery(this).remove();
    });
    newTable.find('.tbody .tr').remove();

    table.parent().parent().parent().prepend(newTable);
    newTable.wrap("<div/>");
    newTable.parent().addClass('fixed-head__wrap');

    newTable.width(newTable.attr('data-item-original-width'));
    newTable.find('.thead .tr .th').each(function(){
        jQuery(this).width(jQuery(this).attr("data-item-original-width"));
    });
    table.width(table.attr('data-item-original-width'));
    table.find('.tbody .tr:eq(0) .td').each(function(){
        jQuery(this).width(jQuery(this).attr("data-item-original-width"));
    });
}
```

Where `table` is you table element (i.e. `$('table')`).
I realize that this is not specific to mCustomScrollbar but the effect should be the same as what it is doing is taking the `thead` from your original table and copying it into a separate one. This separate table has no `tbody` and has a fixed position. The `thead` is also deleted form the original table so only it's body is left.

I hope this helps with anyone that still wants to achieve a fixed header effect

I was able to customize the scrollbar in Chrome using CSS:

```
::-webkit-scrollbar {
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
    background-color:#25628e;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
    background-color: #b2c5d9;
    border-right: 1px solid rgb(169, 169, 169);
}
```

Pleas visit [CSS Tricks](https://css-tricks.com/custom-scrollbars-in-webkit/) for more info

Comment: While moving away from mCustomScrollbar, was this solution able to also allow you to add a custom scrollbar/handle scrolling within? That's a significant reason people use mCustomScrollbar. Either way thanks for the answer - I'll try it out soon

Comment: I have a solution that allows to customise the scrollbar in Chrome. Have yet to try an implementation in IE or Firefox yet. I will amend my answer

Comment: consider making a jsfiddle or an SO code snippet to get a working example of your JS. I've been failing to make it work in a jsfiddle

Comment: I will keep working on my jsFiddle but am having some trouble myself. Will let you know when/if it works

Comment: Another thought: since there seemed to be a conflict between `jquery.floatThead` and `mCustomScrollbar`, did you try going from `mCustomScrollbar` to `Perfect-Scroller`? In the `floatThead` docs it says it plays nicely with that. Did you try that? http://mkoryak.github.io/floatThead/examples/perfect-scrollbar/

Comment: I attempted floatThead with/without mCustomScrollbar but they seemed to conflict in my case